# How can I balance "Pythonic" and "convenient" in this case?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I have an "interface" that will be implemented by client code:

```
class Runner:
    def run(self):
        pass
```

`run` should in general return a `docutils` `node` but because the far far most
common case is plain text, the caller allows `run` to return a string, which will be
checked using `type()` and turned into a `node`.

However, the way I understand "Pythonic", this is not "Pythonic" because
checking the `type()` of something doesn't let it "be" a type by "acting" like
one -- ie "Pythonic" code should use duck typing.

I considered

```
def run_str(self):
    pass

def run_node(self):
    return make_node(self.run_str())
```

but I don't care for this because it puts the not-so-interesting return type
right there in the name; it's distracting.

Are there any ideas I've missed? Also, are there problems I might encounter
down the road with my "bad" system (it seems more or less safe to me)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you talking about the value passed to `run` (via `arg`)? Or are you talking about how to handle the hypothetical value returned by the `run` method of an object that implements the `Runner` interface?

Comment: I mean the return. I edited out the `arg` so it wouldn't distract (thanks for pointing this out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a slightly deceptive example; there's something you haven't stated. I'm guessing that when you say you "have an interface," what you mean is that you have some code that accepts an object and calls its `run` method.

If you aren't testing for the type of that object before calling its `run` method, the you're using duck typing, plain and simple! (In this case, if it has a `run` method, then it's a `Runner`.) As long as you don't use `type` or `isinstance` on the object with a `run` method, then you're being Pythonic.

The question of whether you should accept plain strings or only node objects is a subtly different question. Strings and `node` objects probably don't implement the same interface at all! Strings fundamentally *don't* quack like a `node`, so you don't have to treat them like one. This is like an elephant that comes along, and if you want it to quack like a duck, you have to give the elephant a tape player and train the elephant to use it first.

So this isn't a matter of "duck typing" any more, but of interface design. You're trying to decide how strict you want your interface to be.

To give you an answer, then, at this level, I think it's most Pythonic to assume that `run` returns a `node` object. There's no need to use `isinstance` or `type` to test for that. Just pretend it's a `node` object and if the programmer using your interface gets that wrong, and sees an exception, then they'll have to read your docstring, which will tell them that `run` should pass a `node` object.

Then, if you *want* to also accept strings, or things that quack like strings, you can do so. And since strings are rather primitive types, I would say it's not inappropriate to use `isinstance(obj, basestring)` (but *not* `type(obj) == str` because that rejects unicode strings, etc.). Essentially, this is you being very liberal and kind to lazy users of your program; you're already going above and beyond by accepting elephants as well as things that quack like ducks.

(More concretely, I'd say this is a bit like calling `iter` on an argument at the beginning of a function that you want to accept both generators and sequences.)

Comment: This is a good tradeoff of "Pythonic purity" vs. pragmatic API design. I would also anticipate that your users will "return" None by failing to return anything at all, so you should also code for that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to have methods to handle each type, especially if a simple operation is all that will occur. A common Pythonic approach would be to do something like:

```
def run(self):
    try:
        ...assume it's a str   
    except TypeError:
        ...oops, not a str, we'll address that
```

This follows the [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EAFP)](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) style of coding, which is generally faster and simpler.

Comment: I think we make be talking about different things, I meant the return type; but your answer would apply there too -- it might work well in my case.

Comment: I think it's generally a bad idea to have a method return completely different types of objects. I'd much prefer to deal with two separate methods in that case.

Comment: No you're right, it *is* bad; it's just it's so *convenient* that it's tempting right now.

Comment: A tiny convenience now is not worth the headache later, as I'm sure you realize. Just make your `run()` method handle your common case, the secondary method `run_node()` can handle the less common situation (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Errors and Exceptions.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) You could do something like this:

```
def run(self,arg):
    try:
        return make_node(arg)
    except AlreadyNodeError:
        pass
```

Inside your make_node function, have it raise a AlreadyNodeError if the argument is already a node.

Comment: Doesn't this shift the unkosher call to `type()` into the `make_node()` function?

Comment: Not if the make_node function has a Try: Raise: block in which it attempts to make it into a node and, upon discovering it is already a node, Raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using `type()` to detect a variable's type is really a bad practice, as it wouldn't allow an object inheriting from the desired type (`str` in your case), a better way is to use `isinstance()`:

```
if isinstance(my_var, str):
    my_code_here()
```

Also, a pythonic way of doing this would be duck-typing as you mentionned, why don't you just put the code in a `try`/`except` block? So an exception would be catched only if the value doesn't **act** as expected (if it quacks and walks like a duck, it's a duck).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node(object):
  def __new__(cls, contents):
    return contents if isinstance(contents, cls) else object.__new__(cls)
  def __init__(self, contents):
    # construct from string...

class Manager(object):
  def do_something(self, runner, *args):
    do_something_else(Node(runner(*args)))
```

Now it doesn't matter if the runner returns a Node or a string.